# Losing information using Zonal Statistics?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I produced a raster map representing estimates of the number inhabitants in pixels of 100x100 meter and I want to calculate the total of inhabitants per administrative units that are represented by polygons such as those shown in the picture. After converting those polygons into a raster layer (with a resolution of 100 meter). I'm using Zonal Statistic as Table in ArcGIS to calculate the number of inhabitants per administrative unit. The resultant table has fewer lines than the number of administrative units represented in the raster layer. Therefore I'm losing information for administrative units having an area below 28500 square meters or for administrative units with an irregular geometry such as those highlighted in the picture. The problem persists when I convert the administrative units into a raster layer with a resolution of 25 meter.

[image]

Comment: I would note that you might see strange behavior when your polygons are roughly the same size (or smaller than) your grid cells--it depends on how Arc handles this. Here's a link that might make that a bit clearer, but it's for QGIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276794/how-does-qgiss-zonal-statistics-handle-partially-overlapping-pixels It might have something to do with whether the polygon contains a grid cell center.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue while using Zonal Statistics as Table. I lost several lines of data in my output table because some of my polygons had the same ID name.

When you indicate your "zone field" in the tool, make sure that whatever field you are choosing has completely unique values. Otherwise, you will lose information in your output table. Hopefully this solves your problem as well!