Calculate weighted raster values per polygon depending on overlap with vector layer
I have a raster layer in which pixel values represent percent cover of shrubs per pixel. Since each pixel is 100 m^2, I can use the percent cover as the area, e.g., a value of 5% would equal 5 m^2 shrub cover of that pixel.
Now I also have a vector layer with polygons representing 10 m buffers around transects, with each transect having a unique identifier. I want to calculate the total shrub cover per transect based on how much each pixel overlaps each polygon.
I have been trying to use the Zonal Statistics tool in QGIS but do not think it is taking a weighted sum of pixel values.
Do you have any suggestions?


The Zonal Exact Extract plugin for QGIS will calculate this, taking into account how much each pixel is covered by the polygon.

I believe Zonal Statistics is calculating weighted average. Are you sure it doesnt when you use it?
I have a raster with values from 0-100 and a polygon layer with two polygons in it.
The first polygon is intersecting two pixels.
The second is intersecting three, the white one in the center is nodata.
I've calculated average using Zonal Statistics and compare to a manual calculation of weighted avg and they match.
If the mean werent weighted they would calculate to:
Zone 1: (6.075+94.66)/2 = 50.3675
Zone 2: (79.461+40.901)/2 = 60.181



It depends on the size and shape of the polygons; see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/281753/18189

You can use the tool "Raster pixels to polygons" to retrieve a polygon layer, with the extent and resolution of your raster layer. Each polygon holds the value of the pixel it was derived from. Next, you use "Overlap analysis" with the polygons as input and your transects as overlay layer. The resulting overlap layer holds the precentage of coverage per raster pixel (total cover area and cover percentage). You can use the percentages and your raster values to compute the weighted value for each pixel. Finally you can use the following expression aggregate( 'overlap_layer', 'sum', "weighted_val", intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent) ) ) ('overlap_layer' = name of your overlap layer, "weighted_val" = field name of the field with your weighted values from the previous step). This expression gives you the sum of your weighted values that also intersect with your transects.
EDIT: altered expression using "sum" instead of "mean"
